# How can I show names of fields not validate in error message on submit?

Tags: flutter, validation

When the save button is pressed, if the form is valid it will be saved successfully, but if it is not valid you will get error message "Please resolve given errors" and under every required field there is error message 'required Field'. I want to add the names of required fields that are not filled to the message that shows when save button is pressed (to this message "Please resolve given errors"). How I can do that?

here is the submit function

```
 void _submit() {
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  _save();
}
else if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
          content: Text("Please resolve given errors")
      ));
  return;
}
_formKey.currentState.save();}
```

here is one of my TextFormField

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText:
      AppLocalizations.of(context)
          .getTranslated('firstName'),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.circular(
              5.0))),
  controller: firstNameController,
  validator: (String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return AppLocalizations.of(context)
          .getTranslated('requiredField');
    }
    return null;
  },
  onChanged: (value) {
    debugPrint(
        'Something changed in Username Text Field');
    user.firstName =
        firstNameController.text;
  },
)
```

Comment: You have to set the validator to your `TextFormField`. please show your `Textfield` I will give an example according to your code

Comment: ok,  now I show you one of my TextFormField but I already did that(set the validator to my TextFormField) , what i want to do is show the name of field in the message that shows when the whole form is not validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a List of String

```
List<String> hintList = [];
```

Then in textFormField validator check if the value is empty, then add the hint to hintList

```
TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "First name",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
            controller: firstNameController,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                if(!hintList.contains("First name")){
                  hintList.add("First name");
                }
                return 'Required field!';
              }
              if (hintList.contains("First name")) {
                hintList.removeWhere((element) => element == "First name");
              }
              return null;
            },
            onChanged: (value) {
              user.firstName = firstNameController.text;
            },
          )
```

Then on Save button pressed, put onSubmit function. if formkey not validate then show hintlist empty, else call save() func

```
void submit() {
if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
  save();
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text("${hintList.join(", ")} fields empty!"),
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  ));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with validation or errorText.
I Like work with errorText and validation in separate method.

First, create a validation method:

```
String? validateEmail(String? value){
    
    
    if ((value??'').isEmpty){
    setState(()=>{emailError = 'Cannot be empty'});  
    } else {
      setState(()=>{emailError = ''});  
    }
         
    return emailError;
  }
```

So.. in your TextFormField put a errorText.

```
TextFormField(
               style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
             
              decoration: InputDecoration(                
                errorText: (emailError != null &&( emailError??'').isEmpty )? null :emailError.toString(),
              ),
              controller: _myController,
            )
```

In button click you call the validation method.

Answer (score 0):

I made a minimal example of what you want:

I don't think you need the textController.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Map<String, String> values = {"name": "", "age": "", "number": ""};
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                validator: ((value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) return "Required Field";
                }),
                onChanged: ((v) {
                  values.update("name", (value) => v);
                }),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                validator: ((value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) return "Required Field";
                }),
                onChanged: ((v) {
                  values.update("age", (value) => v);
                }),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                validator: ((value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) return "Required Field";
                }),
                onChanged: ((v) {
                  values.update("number", (value) => v);
                }),
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _submit(values);
                  },
                  child: Text("Submit"))
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  void _submit(Map<String, String> values) {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      // _save();
    } else if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      var list =
          values.entries.where((element) => element.value.isEmpty).toList();
      if (list.length == 1) {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState!
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("${list[0].key} is empty")));
      } else if (list.length == 2) {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text("${list[0].key} and ${list[1].key} are empty")));
      } else if (list.length == 3) {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(
                "${list[0].key},${list[1].key},and ${list[2].key} are empty")));
      }
    }
    _formKey.currentState!.save();
  }
}
```